# Sql convert to orm doctrine Symfony2

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have this SQL and is work on phpmyadmin

```
SELECT package.name, geography.name, g2.name, package.id, geography.id, 
       g2.id FROM package left join hotel on package.hotel_id = hotel.id 
left join geography on hotel.location = geography.id 
left join geography g2 on geography.parent_id = g2.id
```

I want convert in doctrine Symfony2 and tried something...

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('package')
     ->select('package.name','geography.name','package.id','geography.id')
     ->from('FNETJmbBundle:Package', 'package')
         ->leftJoin('FNETJmbBundle:Hotel', 'hotel', 'WITH', 'package.hotel=hotel.id')
     ->leftJoin('FNETJmbBundle:Geography', 'geography',  'WITH', 'hotel.location=geography.id')
     ->leftJoin('FNETJmbBundle:Geography', 'g2',  'WITH', 'geography.parent_id=g2.id')
      ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Errors:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 290 near 'parent_id=g2': Error: Class FNET\JmbBundle\Entity\Geography has no field or association named parent_id
>
> QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 290 near 'parent_id=g2': Error: Class FNET\JmbBundle\Entity\Geography has no field or association named parent_id

Comment: Your error is related to entities, therefore it would be easier if you provide its code including mapping. What I can guess is that you should use property name instead of sql field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in geography entity if you have declared a property named "parent_id" (You should use the property noun and not the column noun when you create your query builder).